# Pixiedust table in loop in r markdown not rendering

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Relevant to the problem, I have a dataset with factors of states ("Massachusetts", "California", etc) and 2 fields of values. I would like to create a graph for each state with a table below it showing the associated fields and the difference between those fields. 
I found that using a loop seems to require a results = 'asis' option and a cat("  \n") at the end of the loop to print the images. That works OK. However, the only way I can seem to get a table is if I use xtable or kable. I would like to use pixiedust to color and otherwise beautify the table.

Here is a minimal example:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(pixiedust)
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
library(xtable)

df <- data.frame(state = c("MA", "CA"), last_year = c(105, 90), this_year     = c(110, 85))

```

# Here is the loop

```{r loops, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE}

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  state_dat <- df[i,]
  p1 <- ggplot(state_dat, aes(last_year, this_year)) +
    geom_point()
  print(p1)
  cat("  \n")

  tab <- data.frame(last_year = state_dat$last_year, this_year = state_dat$this_year, yoy_percent = 100*(state_dat$this_year - state_dat$last_year)/state_dat$last_year)

dust(tab) %>%
    sprinkle(rows = 1, bg = "orchid")
  cat("  \n")

print(kable(tab, row.names = FALSE, align = "c"))
cat("  \n")

print(xtable(tab, auto = TRUE),type = "html", comment = FALSE, include.rownames = F) 
cat("  \n")

}
```
````

I also tried assigning the result of the dust commands to an object and printing that:

```
pixie <- dust(tab) %>%
    sprinkle(rows = 1, bg = "orchid")
print(pixie)
cat("  \n")
```

to no avail.

Can pixiedust tables be produced as html in a chunk with option asis? Is there another workaround to produce a table and a graph in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done.  To get there, you have to turn off the `asis` printing in the `print.dust` method.  This can be done with:

```
dust(tab) %>%
    sprinkle(rows = 1, bg = "orchid") %>% 
  print(asis = FALSE) %>% 
  cat()
```

In time, I hope to come up with a better solution.